# R: SQUAREM vs. TURBOEM for fixed point convergence?

Tags: r

I have a calculation in R that needs to iteratively call a function for a fixed point contraction mapping.  I've been using the `squarem` function out of the `SQUAREM` package by Ravi Varadhan.  Today while trying to figure out a way around an issue I was having with `squarem` I came across the `TURBOEM` package, also by Varadhan.  At first glance `TURBOEM` seems to do the same things as `SQUAREM`, but with additional functionality in some dimensions.

Does anyone know whether one or the other of these packages is preferred, either in general or for particular applications? Is one more current/updated than the other?  `TURBOEM` seems to have the ability to customize the convergence criterion, which might get me out of the current bind I'm in, but I'm concerned there might be other issues.  Obviously I can go off and test the corresponding functions from each package, but if someone out there knows some background on the two packages it might save me a ton of time.

Comment: did you get any update on this? Even I'm trying to use turboEM for mixtures of distribution but I'm not getting enough info on it

Comment: Never got an update.  I'm forgetting what tests I ran, but I eventually convinced myself that TURBOEM and SQUAREM were turning out equivalent results in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four underlying SQUAREM algorithms used by each package. They are effectively identical*. You can see the underlying functions for yourself by using:

```
SQUAREM:::cyclem1
SQUAREM:::cyclem2
SQUAREM:::squarem1
SQUAREM:::squarem2
turboEM:::bodyCyclem1
turboEM:::bodyCyclem2
turboEM:::bodySquarem1
turboEM:::bodySquarem2
```

* apart from some differences due to the way in which these are used within the packages. And the argument `method` in `SQUAREM` is called `version` in `turboEM`

I would say `turboEM` would probably be preferred in general, for the following reasons:

- As you mention, `turboEM` allows the user to select the convergence criterion, either based on the L2-norm of the change in the parameter vector (`convtype = "parameter"`), the L1-norm of the change in the objective function (`convtype = "objfn"`), or by specifying a custom function (`convfn.user`). `SQUAREM` only checks convergence using the L2-norm of the change in parameter vector.
- `turboEM` can also stop the algorithm prior to convergence based on either the number of iterations (`stoptype = "maxiter"`) or the amount of time elapsed (`stoptype = "maxtime"`). `SQUAREM` only stops after the specified number of iterations.
- The `pconstr` and `project` arguments to `turboem` allow the user to define parameter space constraints and a function that projects estimates back into the parameter space if these are violated. `SQUAREM` does not have this functionality.
- `turboEM` can easily apply multiple versions of the algorithm to the same data (e.g. with different orders, step sizes, ...), by providing a vector to the `method` argument and a `list` to the `control.method` argument...
- ... and it can do this in parallel via the `foreach` package.
- `turboEM` also offers a convenient interface through which to apply a vanilla EM algorithm, as well as EM acceleration schemes other than SQUAREM: parabolic EM (`method = "pem"`), dynamic ECME (`"decme"`) and quasi-Newton (`"qn"`).
- The `turboEM` package also provides the `turboSim` function, which allows the user to easily conduct benchmark studies comparing the different acceleration schemes.

The one downside that I can see to using `turboEM` instead of `SQUAREM` is that, if you are really interested in the particulars of the SQUAREM algorithm, the `trace` provided by `squarem` gives more specific information (residual, extrapolation, step length) than that provided by `turboem` (objective function [if calculated], iteration number, L2-norm of parameter change).

One final aside: The current version of [`SQUAREM` on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SQUAREM/index.html) (v 2016.8-2) has indeed been updated more recently than the version of [`turboEM` on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/turboEM/index.html) (v 2014.8-1). However, the NEWS suggests that the only updates to `SQUAREM` since December 2010 have been vignettes and demos, while `turboEM`'s first release was in December 2011.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.  Bonus points for catching that the internals of turboEM are actually more recently released than SQUAREM.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in SQUAREM and turboEM.  I am the author of both packages. In future, you may contact me directly with any questions.

The goals of the 2 packages are different.  SQUAREM implements one class of acceleration methods. turboEM on the other hand includes a variety of state-of-art EM acceleration techniques.  The goal of turboEM is to provide a go-to-place for all your EM acceleration needs!  In particular, turboEM allows you to benchmark the different algorithms for your problem and determine the best one.  In my experience, the squarem class of algorithms most often out perform the other 3 classes (quasi-Newton, dynamic EM, and parabolic EM). Hence, you might also directly use the SQUAREM package.  However, turboEM has a number of additional features as pointed out by Mark.

Ravi Varadhan